# Помогите найти реализцаию алгоритма Divide and Conquer на c#

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Я знаю что этот алгоритм очень похож на merge sort, однако я не нашел в интернете его реализацию (функцию) на языке c#

Comment: Это название принципа построения, а не конкретного алгоритма. Примерно как просить подарить даже не килограмм еды, а 2000 килокалорий...

Comment: Тогда скинь алгоритм, который использует этот принцип

Comment: @Gregory Классический mergesort или quicksort ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь все подробно описанно:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-arrays-set-3-using-divide-and-conquer-approach/

Вот кусок divide:

```
static void divide(int l, int r, int[] output, int [,]arr)  
{  
    if (l == r) 
    {  

        /* base step to initialize the output  
        array before performing merge  
        operation */
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
            output[l * n + i] = arr[l, i];  

        return;  
    }  

    // to sort left half  
    divide(l, (l + r) / 2, output, arr);  

    // to sort right half  
    divide((l + r) / 2 + 1, r, output, arr);  

    // merge the left and right half  
    merge(l, r, output);  
}
```